# In Razor, how do I set current Model scope?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I am not even sure how I would ask this question.  Basically, you know how in Razor you have stuff like this:

```
@model MyProj.childObj
// Current scope is childObj
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyVal)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyVal2)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyVal3)
...
```

This all work fine and dandy, but what if I concat childObj into another obj?  So for example:

```
@model MyProj.parentObj
```

So now, I can do this:

```
// Current scope is parentObj
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.childObj.MyVal)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.childObj.MyVal2)
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.childObj.MyVal3)
...
```

which is fine, but since I have a lot of variable, I would like to do this instead:

```
// Current scope is parentObj
@using (Model.childObj) {
    // Current scope is now childObj
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyVal)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyVal2)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MyVal3)
    ...
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You can define variables within Razor and use them.

```
@{
    var child = Model.childObj;
    @Html.LabelFor(m => child.MyVal)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => child.MyVal2)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => child.MyVal3)
}
```

Comment: Works well, only change I had to make was to remove m declaration because it is already delcared (by defualt?)/

Comment: Change your local variable from `m` to `m2`.  This will disambiguate the local variable `m` and the predicate parameter `m`.